# Question with NSTextField

Tags: objective-c

I have this code that changes the text of an NSTextField

```
[TextField setStringValue: [PrinterCard print]];
```

(PrinterCard print returns an NSString) What I want to do now is I want to append the PrinterCard print string to the text of TextField. I also want to do this on the next line, so I want basically to append this:

`@"\n%@", [PrinterCard Print]`

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@",[PrinterCard Print]]
```

Comment: I know how to do that, the important part was how do I add text on to the end of the already existing text that is in the TextField. I was thinking something like [TextField appendStringValue:[PrinterCard Print]];

Comment: for appending string you can use 
string1 = [string1 stringByAppendingString:string2];